# Adding wrapper elements in the_date() like in the_title()?

Tags: php, functions, templates, page-template

So this works:

```
the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
```

But this does not:

```
the_date( '<h4 class="entry-date">', '</h4>' );
```

I don't know enough if this is reserved for `the_title()` or if the twentyfifteen theme has specified this functionality in functions. I don't see it but I could be missing it. Or course, just printing `the_date();` works as it's supposed to as well as pulling it out of the php block and wrapping it in html myself also works. Just thought there could be a nifty little way to do it like `the_title` there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date) ( or [Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_date/) ) is a fantastic tool when you're unsure about a function. Looking at the parameter list for [`the_date()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date) it says:

```
the_date( $format, $before, $after, $echo );
```

So you need to pass in [a format](https://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time) as the first parameter, then your HTML tags like you have it. An example could look like this:

```
the_date( 'l, F j, Y', '<h4 class="entry-date">', '</h4>' );
```

Answer (score 0):

The [the_date](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date) function does not work like that.

The first parameter is the [date format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) you want to use.

To echo it out

> the_date( 'F j, Y', '', '', true );

To get the result:

> $result = the_date('F j, Y', '', '', false );

You might also want to see [get_the_date](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_the_date).

Comment: `the_date()` would work like that if you used the second and third parameters appropriately instead of leaving them as empty strings.